# How can I get the ListNumber in a docx by using python-docx

Tags: python-docx

I am trying to get the style of each paragraph in a docx by using "paragraph.style.name".

However, I can only get:

```
           "Heading 1"
           "Heading 2"
            "Normal"
            "Normal"
               .
               .
```

but no "List 1", "List 2" as expected.

How to get the ListNumber of a listed paragraph?
Or any other style information can I get except "Normal"?

Comment: Please add some example code that describe how are you doing the things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the list numbering being applied manually using the toolbar icon rather than by using a style. In this case the style would be unchanged, which would explain why it might appear as "Normal".

The list numbering details will be found in the paragraph properties and will involve several references to the `numbering.xml` part. Your best bet if you want to tackle it would be to start by browsing the XML; `opc-diag` is good for that.

But it's pretty complicated and I know of no examples you can follow.